# Rails sending faxes with efax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, fax

I'm building a Rails app where I need to send a record to a recipient's fax number.  I'd like to use Efax to accomplish this.

Most of the recipient's do not have an efax email address otherwise I'd just use a mailer to send it that way.

Is there a Rails plugin that utilizes Efax to send outbound faxes to actual fax numbers?

Comment: I would love to see an answer explaining how to hack ActionMailer to add a fax function that reuses the existing mailer views. Phaxio let's you post an HTML file and converts it to a fax for you, so I wouldn't have to create new templates...

Answer (score 2):

I searched rubygems.org for efax and found the efax gem.

http://rubygems.org/gems/efax

https://github.com/szimek/efax

Efax itself requires you to sign up to be able to use the API, but you can contact them for a free trial.

Also see the http://www.efaxdeveloper.com/developer/howWorks

Detailed API info and sample faxes can be found (pick the Universal Implementation Kit) at
https://secure.efaxdeveloper.com/downloads.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Hello Fax instead of Efax as it was more flexible and the API was easily accessible to developers.  I used the hello_fax gem here: [hello_fax ruby gem](https://github.com/maletor/hello_fax)